# React can not use conditionally rendering on a component due to variables being nested inside of my form

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I want to conditionally render a component in this case  if the user submits a wrong answer, the input is stored as a javascript object called data and gets converted to a string called userInput.

After looking around, I got recommended to create a conditional rendering with a state outside of the form, but the problem I ran across is that since the variables are initialized inside of my form, i can't use ternaries to conditionally render my component in so I'm a bit stuck in what to do.

```
 <main class="gameSection">
        
        <h1>Welcome to League of Wordle!</h1>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {

            let userInput = data.guess;
            console.log(userInput);
            const championList = Object.keys(champions);


            if (userInput.valueOf().toUpperCase() !== correctChampion.valueOf().toUpperCase()) {
              <Wrong text="Class" alt="wrong img" img={wrong} />
            }
          })

          }
        >
          <input 
          {...register("guess")} class="guess_input" placeholder="Enter Champion Name Here" type="text" />
          <input class="guess_input" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a `state` to track if any answers submitted is wrong.

```
const [isWrong, setIsWrong] = useState(false)
```

Now, after each submit, update `isWrong`'s value based on input.

```
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {

        let userInput = data.guess;
        console.log(userInput);
        const championList = Object.keys(champions);


        if (userInput.valueOf().toUpperCase() !== correctChampion.valueOf().toUpperCase()) {
          setIsWrong(true)
        }
        else {setIsWrong(false) } // logic in case of correct answer
      })

      }
```

Finally, you can implement conditional rendering:

```
 <main class="gameSection">
    
    <h1>Welcome to League of Wordle!</h1>
    <form
      ...
    >
      <input 
      {...register("guess")} class="guess_input" placeholder="Enter Champion Name Here" type="text" />
      <input class="guess_input" type="submit" />
      {isWrong && <Wrong text="Class" alt="wrong img" img={wrong} /> }
    </form>
  </main>
```